# Optimize mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache

I have a web hosting service that has 65k rules, some of those rules are obsolete some lead to loops. I wonder is there any tool that reads the logs or takes some set of requests and optimizes rules or offer suggestions?

Comment: Sounds interesting. Are you bound to any OS (i.e. must the script support a given OS, or is one preferred)? Also, if it comes to paid solution, what's your limit? And shall it just optimize *existing* rules – or also propose new ones (in the latter case, on what base)?

Comment: I run apache on ubuntu, it should also propose new rules.
I am looking into writing it myself, are you interested in writing it together?

Comment: If I wanted to do everything I'm interested in, a day needed to have 96 hours – so sorry, no, I have to focus on the things at hand here :) // So if you run Apache on Ubuntu, the program *must* run on that – or should *preferably* run there (with other solutions acceptable)? An example on how it should create new rules would be interesting as well, even if "raw" (just to get an idea).